# Where is htdocs for binami lampp stack? Do I have to make it?

Tags: bitnami, lampp, htdocs

I used XAMP yesterday and my htdocs was in an easy location under `/opt/lampp/lampp`. I can't seem to find it using bitnami LAMPP. Does anyone know where it is for Ubunutu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bitnami developer here,

The htdocs directory for LAMPP is:

> lampp_installdir/htdocs

If you have installed XAMPP as root user, the default dir is:

> /opt/lampp/htdocs

If you want to install a module on the LAMPP, it will be placed in lampp_installdir/apps/app_name. For example, if you install the WordPress module on the LAMPP, its htdocs directory should be in:

> lampp_installdir/apps/wordpress/htdocs.

I hope it helps

David